# Why doesn't Jane Chatwin simply go back in time and kill Martin?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-magicians

Season one of The Magicians revolves around defeating "The Beast" or Martin. It's revealed that Jane is The Watcherwoman messing around with time and changing specific variables each time she sets a new "time loop".

So why not simply go back in time and kill Martin while he's in Fillory?

---

This is somewhat similar to "use a Time Turner, kill Tom Riddle" but that theory can be disregarded because the time turner only  lasts one hour. In the Magicians on the other hand Jane can frolic around time as much as she pleases

Comment: Presumably because stopping the Beast was preferable to *killing her brother*

Comment: "we don't know the extent of a time Turner's capacity to go back in time" We do, actually. They're quite limited and a great many things can go wrong if you try to travel too far back beyond just getting spotted by your previous self and others. https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/time-turner

Comment: Related question: when Quentin tells her “you die this time”, why not start a new loop?

Answer (score 2):

Quentin and Julia both have visited timelines in which they fail to kill the Beast. The Beast continued to wreak havoc and terrorize everyone at Brakebills. Killing/stopping the Beast in the current timeline didn't change that.

Going back in time may fix another timeline, but it won't fix the timeline in which the Beast already exists. That is the timeline that the show focuses on.

Answer (score -1):

In the TV show, she told Quentin that she did that but also everybody was dead, so she keep coming back in time to make the physical kids kill him (like a lot times). Also if she would do that a lot of little thing could change because of the butterfly effect.